# Adding an element on specific rows of a grid using Tkinter

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

Is there a way to add a button in specifics rows on a grid using Tkinter toolkit?

I am currently trying to get a grid setup like this:

[image]

Where the red rectangles are the elements of the grid (buttons).
As you can see, the second line has one additional button compared to the first, and so on.

So, am looking for a way to display one additional button to specifics rows in my grid, if possible.

Here is the code :

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 


fenetre = Tk()

#frame 1
Frame1 = Frame(fenetre, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
Frame1.pack(fill=BOTH)

#frame2
Frame2 = Frame(fenetre, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
Frame2.pack(fill=BOTH)

#grid display
def afficheGrille():

    tailleGrille=(int(s.get()))

    for ligne in range((tailleGrille * 2) +1):
        for colonne in range(tailleGrille):
            if(ligne == 0 or (ligne % 2) == 0):
                #boutons horizontaux
                Button(Frame2, borderwidth=1, height=1, width=8).grid(row=ligne, column=colonne)
            else:
                #boutons verticaux
                Button(Frame2, borderwidth=1, height=5, width=2).grid(row=ligne, column=colonne)



label = Label(Frame1, text="Jeu du carré")
label.pack()

boutonJvIA=Button(Frame1, text="1 joueur vs IA", width=30, command=afficheGrille)
boutonJvIA.pack()

boutonJvJ=Button(Frame1, text="1 joueur vs 1 joueur", width=30, command=afficheGrille)
boutonJvJ.pack()

s = Spinbox(Frame1, from_= 0, to = 100)
s.pack()



fenetre.mainloop()
```

Thank you by advance.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  That looks like a straightforward 5x5 grid, with horizontal buttons in the odd columns of even rows, and vertical buttons in the even columns of odd rows.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think you need to rephrase it. Also running your code is outputs a GUI which is too different from what you want to achieve as highlighted by your "red" image

Comment: The problem is that I had the same number of buttons on every line, and did not find a way to solve that. But as jason said, I will finally display a grid of 5x5 buttons (the white ones will not do anything). Thank you anyway

Comment: Are you aware you can specify the exact row and column when using `grid` instead of `pack`?

Comment: by the way, Tk has GUI builders ;)

Comment: again, my recommendation when you have complex Tk widgets placements to use GUI builders instead, and then to check (or use) generated code, there are many of them: http://wiki.tcl.tk/4056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adjusting the indices in your for loops and specifying the correct `row` and `column` arguments in the `.grid()` method, you will get the alignment you want:

```
for ligne in range( tailleGrille*2 + 1):
    if (ligne % 2) == 0:
        #boutons horizontaux
        for colonne in range(tailleGrille):
            Button(Frame2, bd=1, height=1, width=8).grid(row=ligne, column=2*colonne+1)
    else:
        #boutons verticaux
        for colonne in range(tailleGrille + 1):
            Button(Frame2, bd=1, height=5, width=2).grid(row=ligne, column=2*colonne)
```